# How do I reload a NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an app that preloads a months worth of data and it gets released a day at a time.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

      // Create predicate

      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(location.name == %@) AND (date < %@)",longLocation,now];
```

Everything worked great before multi-tasking, but now that it no longer starts from nil I cannot get it to recognize the new date and reload the data based on that new date.

I have the view loaded into a TabBarController.  It seems to want to hang onto that view forever and I can't seem to get viewWillAppear to do anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your fetchRequestController uses a cache and if you want to modify the fetchRequest (for example changing a predicate) you have delete the cache before using performFetch again